# how do you deal with extra records that was created, but not used?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

it's a common pattern to createRecord in the model hook when user enters the route.

Sometimes those records remain unused, and they pops up in certain conditions, i.e. in peekAll query, although that is unwanted. How do deal with them?

Comment: There are a couple of ways, you can just use a POJO instead of a record in the model hook, you can remove the record when you leave the route if unused.

Comment: This isn't handled by Ember Data itself?

Comment: How would Ember Data know that you decided against using a record?  It's important to realize that Ember and ED are two different products.  ED isn't part of the Ember codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If creation is the main responsibility for the route, you could destroy model on `deactivate` route event, for example:

```
//route
model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('modelName');
},

cleanModel: function() {
    var model = this.modelFor( this.routeName );
    if (model.get('isNew')) {
        model.destroyRecord();
    }
}.on('deactivate')
```

[Deactivate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_deactivate) event is triggered when the router completely exits this route. It is not executed when the model for the route changes.