# How to destroy a route model on transition in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember application I have two routes, `people` and `person`.

When I transition into person the value of the current model is binded to a property in the application controller.

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: [ 'person' ],
  currentPerson: Ember.computed('controllers.person.currentPerson', function () {
    var person = this.get('controllers.person.currentPerson');
    return person ? 'selected person #' + person.id : 'no one has been selected';
  })
});

App.PersonController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentPerson: Ember.computed.alias('model')
});
```

When I transition out of the `person` route I want to clear the value, ideally destroying the `person` model.

I've tried:

```
willTransition: function () {
  this.get('model').destroy();
}
```

But this doesn't work. How do I properly delete the cached route model?

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xogati/1/edit?html,js,output

Thanks!

Comment: deactivate route event, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31162420/4950029

Answer (score 2):

The `willTransition` hook should work. By the code you have, it looks like you may be using it incorrectly. [willTransition](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_willTransition) is an event on the route, but you're using `this.get('model')` and there is no `model` property on the route (it's on the controller). Here is the full code you want that should accomplish what you need.

```
App.PersonRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        willTransition: function(transition) {
            this.get('controller.model').destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

As a side note, there's a lot of quirkiness with transitions and when they're fired (if at all). If you find that this won't work for you in some cases, you may want to take a look at the [deactivate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_deactivate) hook instead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, but the `deactivate` hook might be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This seemed to achieve what I wanted, but I'm not sure it's the best way to go.

    `destroyModel: function () {
      this.set('controller.model', null);
    }.on('deactivate')`

Answer (score 0):

Leaving an answer to anyone who stumbles upon this.

The `deactivate` event allows to create an event handler that will teardown the model. For this particular use case I found that `this.set('controller.model', null);` does the job, but assuming you have a more complex model (i.e. ember-data model) you will need to implemented some more logic.

```
destroyModel: function () {
  this.set('controller.model', null);
}.on('deactivate')
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xogati/5/edit?html,js,output

Thanks to @GJK and @Artych.

Answer (score 0):

As a note for future readers, the preferred approach to this at this point is as follows:

In your route file:

```
  actions: {
    willTransition() {
      const modelRecord = this.controller.get('model');

      // toss record changes (or the entire record itself) if it hasn't been saved
      if (modelRecord.get('hasDirtyAttributes')) {
        modelRecord.rollbackAttributes();
      }
    }
  }
```

It's generally advisable to do this in the `willTransition` hook as you will hit snags if you only do this in the `deactivate` hook and you are using nested routes